# Strike through page header in DokuWiki

Tags: dokuwiki

I am looking for a way to strike through page header in DokuWiki. I checked on [Dokuwiki page](https://www.dokuwiki.org/wiki:syntax) but couldn't find it. Can anyone please help me with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative would be to use an external tool like http://manytools.org/facebook-twitter/strikethrough-text/ to generate UTF-8 text that is already stricken through and then to copy&paste it into DokuWiki as your headline.

One advantage is that then also your links will display the headline as stricken through.

Also, you don't have to meddle with custom CSS or additional plugins.

Comment: Brilliant yet simple idea!

Answer (score 1):

> it's a limitation of how headlines work in DokuWiki

See explanation [here](https://www.dokuwiki.org/faq:headerlinks).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you know any other way by which I can give different look to the page header?

Comment: See two links at the bottom of the page with explanation. https://www.dokuwiki.org/tips:styling-headers and https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:header2